# Recyclerview with onTouch and onClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I want to add onTouch for resize recyclerview height and use onClick for select the recyclerview item. But after height of recyclerview resized , i can't use the onClick. Why this is happen? and how to fix it?

This is my sample code:

```
    val pageMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) -1
    val adapter2 = CalendarCobaAdapter2(dayValue, pageMonth, false)


    recyclerview.adapter = adapter2
    recyclerview.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        when(event!!.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                Log.d("OntOUhc","ASD")
                v!!.layoutParams.height = event.getY().toInt()
                v.requestLayout()
            }
        }
        true
    }
    adapter2.setClickListener(this)
```

Comment: try returning `true` only if you actually consumed the event, that should solve your issue. The `boolean` returned by `onTouch`, indeed, tells whether the touch event has been consumed or not

Comment: its work, but when i change the height with onTouch the recyclerview items automatically scrolled. How i can prevent this?

Comment: Uhm I'm not sure I understood what's the issue. Could you please describe it again?

Comment: u can check this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_JMDkL3UiYoTezsdarFsaekk_CIyklJL)

Comment: Are you now returning always `false` for that method?

Comment: yes, i make it return false when using MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , so i can use onClick in recyclerview items

Comment: The question is: how could you do you determine if you want to scroll or resize your `RecyclerView`? To solve the issue, you could maybe draw a little "handle" above your `RecyclerView` and apply your `OnTouchListener` only if the touch event happens inside the area occupied by that "handle", otherwise let Android deal with the default `RecyclerView`'s behavior (i.e., scrolling the list)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , i'll try it

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: Finally i can solve the issue